# Getting error when running `lerna run dev --scope [package-name]

Tags: lerna

When running `lerna run dev --scope [package-name], I got this error bellow

> No packages remain after filtering [ 'package-name' ]

Answer (score 1):

make sure `name` in your package.json is same with your command

**e.g** lerna run dev --scope search-app

in your package.json should looks like below

```
//package.json
{
   "name": "search-app",
}
```